# Is this safe programming for Bison?

Tags: if-statement, bison, yacc

I'm writing a compiler, and I have working code for handling infinitely nested if statements, but it's kind of a hack. I don't know if it's safe to do this?

```
con_statement:
IF exp DO
{
  $1 = ifNum++;
  if($2 == BOOLEAN_TYPE || $2 == INTEGER_TYPE)
    {
      utstring_printf(code, "\tpop\teax\n");
      utstring_printf(code, "\tcmp\teax, 0\n");
      utstring_printf(code, "\tje\tIF_END_%d\n", $1);
    }
  if($2 == FLOAT_TYPE)
    {
      utstring_printf(code, "\tnop\n");
    }
}
program FI
{
  utstring_printf(code, "IF_END_%d:\n", $1);
}
;
```

Comment: What are you concerned about?  The label generation?  The code generation?  The `program` part of the rule?  It isn't clear how you handle ELSE clauses...maybe that doesn't matter, but it often does.

Comment: Saying $1 = LABELNUM and typing a terminal seems like a bad kludge to me? Sorry I forgot to finish typing,

Comment: Since the default action is to set `$$ = $1;`, dinking with `$1` like that might have ramifications upstream, but it shouldn't affect the Yacc code — just any of your actions that looks at the value returned by `con_statement`.  I think it would be more conventional to create a mechanism to associate a label number with the current construct.  I think what you're doing is aconventional.  It think it may have ramifications for you later.  But I don't think it breaks Yacc itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine but it would be IMO clearer to use $$/$4:

```
con_statement:
IF exp DO
{
  $$ = ifNum++;
  if($2 == BOOLEAN_TYPE || $2 == INTEGER_TYPE)
    {
      utstring_printf(code, "\tpop\teax\n");
      utstring_printf(code, "\tcmp\teax, 0\n");
      utstring_printf(code, "\tje\tIF_END_%d\n", $$);
    }
  if($2 == FLOAT_TYPE)
    {
      utstring_printf(code, "\tnop\n");
    }
}
program FI
{
  utstring_printf(code, "IF_END_%d:\n", $4);
}
;
```

The first action is generating a value (which it puts into `$$`), and then later actions can access that value.

Alternately (and particularly if you want to support ELSE), it may make sense to split this initial action onto a separate production:

```
con_statement:
  if_head program FI
    { utstring_printf(code, "IF_FALSE_%d:\n", $1); }
| if_head program ELSE
    { utstring_printf(code, "\tjmp\tIF_END_%d\n", $1);
      utstring_printf(code, "IF_FALSE_%d:\n", $1); }
  program FI
    { utstring_printf(code, "IF_END_%d:\n", $1); }
;

if_head:
  IF exp DO
    { $$ = ifNum++;
          :
;
```

This allows using the same action for plain if and if/else, avoiding a grammar conflict, since at the point you are parsing the `IF..DO` you don't know whether there will be an `ELSE` or not.